# Override HtmlHelper :: link() function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

If there's a better way to achieve what I want to do, please point that out.

I have a multilingual application in CakePHP, and I want to keep the language parameter in each page. What I want to do, is to override the default link function to put a language parameter on each link, unless the language parameter is specified in the input array. I know how to do this, I just need the instructions on how to override the class so I don't have to change my code in lower levels.

Comment: I think you can just write your own custom Helper, which works similar to HtmlHelper.

Comment: The point was overriding the HtmlHelper, because if I make my function in a different one, I would have to change the code in every view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your HtmlHelper as MyHtmlHelper and use aliasing to map it back to `Html` namespace:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers